# Are date code 2010 micrcontrollers OK in 2014?

Tags: microcontroller

The microcontroller we use on our boards have been out of stock for an extended period of time with all the major players, we had enough stock to cover us for 4 months but it's running dry. After pushing digikey a bit they used the 'expediter' to ask Atmel ( i assume ) for some stock.

They found some with date code 2010.

I'm a bit hesitant, what should I keep in mind here, what are the pitfalls?

Comment: Solderability perhaps, nothing else to be worried about.

Comment: NOS is usually okay for solid state devices. But it's still time to port the board and firmware.

Comment: I would NOT assume they came from Atmel, especially with a stale date code. Incoming inspection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They ought to be fine.

If you are soldering with a reflow process (infra-red, hot air or wave) rather than hand soldering, then moisture absorption is a real problem, and after 4 years I would have my doubts however well they are stored.

However this has a solution, whose specific details ought to be documented by the manufacturer : they must be "baked" at an elevated temperature (in the 80C region) for a specified time (hours, possibly overnight) before board assembly, to reduce the moisture content; then soldered within a few days before moisture can build up again.

Comment: Should be SOP for any competent assembly house to bake SMD parts if they're not supplied sealed. Might be a slight surcharge. Only thing to worry about would be if they came out of a warehouse in Taipei (humid as heck) and someone stuck them in a sealed bag like they'd been there all along.

Comment: Agreed. I would still ask the manuf for their recommendations on time and temperature, and abide by those if possible, simply because they are more likely to support that process.

Answer (score 2):

Chips don't go bad like banannas do.  2010 is actually pretty recent.  Think of all the products that have been in the field that long with microcontrollers in them.  How old is your TV, VCR, dishwasher, or car?  Really, there is nothing to worry about here.

About the only issue is for some types of packages that can absorb water vapor and that have been stored in a humid environment.  In extreme cases, such parts can explode during soldering since the water turns to steam but can't escape fast enough.  I have heard of such things, but I store parts in little drawers in my office, often for years, and have never seen anything like that on subsequent soldering.

Comment: Cool. Let's hope they stored them correctly then!

Comment: @user: Really, you're making a mountain out of a molehill. Chill out, dude.

Comment: @user37096 I've read somewhere that chips with increased humidity can be treated in an oven to dry before soldering but I can't provide any details (I think it was printed in a package I received from TI, it had a humidity card and directions in case the card showed more that a specific percentage.)

Comment: @user37096  Seen it for LED's.